Lower alternator bolt stuck on a 1965 Buick, how to get it loose?
I'm trying to replace the alternator on my 1965 Buick Wildcat (401cid Nailhead V8).  I'm pretty sure this alternator was installed in 1990 not long before I purchased the car.
I've gotten the upper bolt off and I've removed the nut from the lower bolt but I have not been able to get the bolt out.

The alternator body will pivot, and I've noticed the head of the bolt rotates as the body pivots.  I've tapped at the bolt but it doesn't budge.
So with that in mind...  Am I overlooking something?  Or is it time to warm it up with a torch and pop it with the hammer some more?

Unfortunately, iron steel bolts and aluminum do not play well together, setting up a galvanic reaction creating their own equivalent of loctite. The (secret) flaw of loctite is heat if a fastener doesn't loosen. With moisture seeping in to accelerates seizing of bolt to aluminum. If you can heat aluminum (it will absorb heat faster and expand faster than the bolt, this should loosen enough to hammer the rusty bolt to force the break. If the bolt loosens, you may be able to grab the bolt head with vise grip pliers to twist it with more penetrant to break up the corrosion for removal.

That's an answer @FDryer.

Just to mention: If you feel that the bolt is stuck so hard that you are in danger of snapping it from excessive torque, then you have a better chance of loosening it without breaking by using whatever the recommended method is (heat, penetrating oil, impact, etc) while torquing first CCW then CW and back again and again, always keeping the torque reasonable so it doesn't snap the bolt. This is most conveniently done with a breaker bar instead of a ratchet so you don't have to keep flipping the direction lever. Back and forth can loosen a bolt when a single pull would break it.
